# How to make Ricoh Aficio SP 100 work on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, 13.10, printing, ricoh

I bought a [Ricoh Aficio SP 100 Monochome Laser Printer](https://ricoh.co.in/products/main-features.aspx?id=180), but have been unable to make it work on Ubuntu 13.10.

The printer has been detected, but the database doesn't have a driver for it. The closest it has to offer is Aficio SP 1000S, which does not work.

On giving command for print, the dialog box shows rendering, then task 'completed', but it does not print anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you should contact Ricoh. From the brochure: Supported ...
Various UNIX/Linux OS

Comment: As Klaus Warzecha said earlier driver project is hosted on [github](https://github.com/madlynx/ricoh-sp100 "github"). (I am the author).
Can you please try again (since 9th Feb there're some improvements)

Answer (score 2):

The printer is not listed at openprinting.org, but it seems that some friendly guy wrote a CUPS driver and hosts it on [github](https://github.com/madlynx/ricoh-sp100).

Please note that I only found the link, I do not own the printer and did not try the driver.

Comment: Thanks Klaus, this solution has not worked either.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulation! Some kind people create for us driver for sp 100 series and 200 series. At least my Ricoh sp111 working. links for you:
https://github.com/madlynx/ricoh-sp100 .
Read install file, and be happy. 
But I think for easy way to install I can some correct install suggestion.

Then use "check-requirements" I get some unavailable packages. For resolve it problem I can't use name packages from "check-requirements". I type unavailable packages bare on command line, and ubuntu suggesting me name for apt-get. After I just use apt-get install "properlyName".

Second. Then I get cups(http://localhost:631/) I connect printer by usb, put on link "add new printer", choose my printer. Only after this step I can find "choose file" for pointing *.ppd.

Comment: Another kind man created deb pakage `ricoh-sp-series` in PPA https://launchpad.net/~lafricain79/+archive/ubuntu/lafricainenvrac