# How to install Ricoh SP-111 printer driver on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ricoh

Having serious issues in installing the Ricoh SP-111 printer driver on Ubuntu 21.04. This is the only issue which I had since I switched to Linux from Windows. As a result I am not able to use my printer. Please guide me through the steps.

Thank You

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/641405/ricoh-sp111-printer-setup-help

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/417627/how-to-make-ricoh-aficio-sp-100-work-on-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: The 'Joel G Mathew' answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/641405/ricoh-sp111-printer-setup-help : The github link is https://github.com/droidzone/ricoh-sp100 .... i.e. now it's : `$ git clone https://github.com/droidzone/ricoh-sp100.git` .